# Attributes of polygons in a shapefile based on largest area intersection with polygons from a different shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlay, vectorization

I have a shapefile of landcover.  It was developed from a raster dataset (the Crop Data Layer).

I also have a grid of 50x50m cells (polygons in a shapefile) I have overlain on the landcover shapefile.  It's only a subset of 1 county at this point, so it's not too terribly large.

I want to give an attribute to each cell that corresponds to the largest landcover category underneath.

I would prefer to do this with the shapefiles, as I made several modifications to the shapefile after converting it from the raster.  But if it can only be done with a raster, then I'll take that route.

I have tried spatial joins and the update overlay tool in vector data.  I have tried to take raster data, convert it to point data, then to raster, then back to polygon, but doing that you lose the habitat code for the data.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like classical resampling problem. By using Resample tool in Data Management >Raster Processing, you can generate a new lattice of choice. As far as i know ArcGIS takes the majority in assigning the raster ressample. However the MAUP still prevails.